# Submitting selected value of SELECT object for dynamically created list

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am dynamically building a SELECT form object on page load for a list of Organization names. I am using a numeric value since I then reference org information based on the selection box.

I thought of dynamically changing the value of a hidden field when the SELECT box is changed, but I can only get the value. I tried including the Org Name as a "title" in the OPTION tag, but I can't seem to retrieve the title. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Code to build SELECT box:

```
dim OrgList(200)
OrgSelect="<select name='Orgs' onchange='OrgPick(this);'>"&vbCrLf
OrgSelect=OrgSelect&"<option value='none' selected>Select one...</option>"&vbCrLf
OrgCount=0
rOrgList.movefirst
do while not rOrgList.eof
  OrgList(OrgCount)=rOrgList("OrganizationName")
  OrgSelect=OrgSelect&"<option value='"&OrgCount&"'>"&rOrgList("OrganizationName")&"</option>"&vbCrLf
  OrgCount=OrgCount+1
  rOrgList.movenext
loop
OrgSelect=OrgSelect&"</select>"
```

---

UPDATE - 2013.12.11 11:22

My OrgPick() javascript function that didn't work:

```
function OrgPick(data)
{
   document.getElementById("yourPick").value = data.title;
}
```

Also, change the 8th line of the SELECT box code to:

```
OrgSelect=OrgSelect&"<option value='"&OrgCount&"' title='"&rOrgList("OrganizationName")&"'>"&rOrgList("OrganizationName")&"</option>"&vbCrLf
```

Comment: What does the OrgPick() function do? Can you post the code for this please?

Comment: The "OrgPick()" function was just what I was using to update the hidden value object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten the ASP-classic code a bit, just to make it easier to read.

```
'Create the HTML for the organization <Select> list
'and send it to the response stream
response.write MakeOrgSelectList("Orgs", "getSelectedOptionText(this);", rOrgList)

' Function MakeOrgSelectList()
'   Parameter name: The HTML name of the control
'   Parameter onChangeEvent: Javascript string to execute on event 'OnChange'
'   Parameter recordset: A database recordset with data.
'   RETURNS: [string] HTML select list
function MakeOrgSelectList(name, onchangeEvent, recordset)
    string html
    html = "<select name='" & name & "' onchange='" & onchangeEvent & "'>" & vbCrLf

    recordset.moveFirst
    if not recordset.EOF AND not recordset.BOF then
        html = html & "<option value='none' selected>Select one...</option>" & vbCrLf

        do while not recordset.EOF
            html = html & vbTab & "<option value='" & recordset("orgID") & "'>" & recordset("OrganizationName") & "</option>" & vbCrLf
            'html = html & vbTab & "<option value='"&OrgCount&"'>"&recordset("OrganizationName")&"</option>" & vbCrLf
            recordset.MoveNext
        loop
    else
        html = html & "<option value='none' selected>no organizations found!</option>" & vbCrLf
    end if

    'return HTML string
    MakeOrgSelectList = html
End function
```

As for the javasscript, use `element.options[element.selectedIndex].text` to get the text of an Select Option.

```
function getSelectedOptionText(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (element.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;
    return element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Comment: Had to tweak it a bit, but the "element.options[element.selectedIndex].text" was the key. Thanks!